# nvd3: Plot going out of the chart area

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using the following code to make a multichart in nvd3:

```
    var data = 
    [{"variableName":"HHs_Index_Income_75K_9999K","contribution":6717418.0,"roi":0.0,"date":1.1997306E12,"spend":131.0},

    {"variableName":"HHs_Index_Income_75K_9999K","contribution":6563584.0,"roi":0.0,"date":1.2033594E12,"spend":128.0},
    ...
    ...
    ...
    {"variableName":"HHs_Index_Income_75K_9999K","contribution":6819974.0,"roi":0.0,"date":1.243881E12,"spend":133.0}];

    function formatOverviewPerformanceTrendsData(data, y1Var , y2Var ) {
        var finalData = new Array();
        var y1Array = new Array();
        var y2Array = new Array();

        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            var dataElement = data[i];
            //var datePattern =new RegExp('/','g');
            //var dateString = dataElement['date'].replace(datePattern,''); 
            var dateString = dataElement['date'];


            var objArray1 = {x: dateString , y:dataElement[y1Var.toLowerCase()]};
            var objArray2 = {x: dateString , y:dataElement[y2Var.toLowerCase()]};
            y1Array.push(objArray1);
            y2Array.push(objArray2);
        }
        var y1Obj = { key:y1Var , type:'line' , yAxis:'1' , values:y1Array};
        var y2Obj = { key:y2Var , type:'line' , yAxis:'2' , values:y2Array};

        finalData.push(y1Obj);
        finalData.push(y2Obj);

        return finalData;
    }

    function render_overview_trends_screen(data) {

        var contributionROIData = formatOverviewPerformanceTrendsData(data,'Contribution','ROI');
        var revenueTrendsData = formatOverviewPerformanceTrendsData(data,'Contribution','Spend');

        nv.addGraph(function() {
            var chart = nv.models.multiChart().margin({
                top : 10,
                right : 80,
                bottom : 40,
                left : 80
            }).color(d3.scale.category10().range());

            chart.xAxis.axisLabel('Date').
            tickFormat(function(d) { 
                return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)); 
            });

            chart.yAxis1.axisLabel('Contribution');

            chart.yAxis2.axisLabel('ROI');

            d3.select('#chart1 svg').datum(contributionROIData)
                    .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

            return chart;
        });

    }

    document.body.onload = function(){
        render_overview_trends_screen(data);
    }
```

But the chart made has the lines plotted outside the chart area.

Please help me through this. As in what exactly is the issue? How do you tinker with the scale/range of nvd3 charts?

Much thanks!

Comment: Is the y axis too small or the x axis?

Comment: Can you post something in a JSFiddle?